# Необработанное исключение

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, async-await

На собеседовании спросили что будет в данной ситуации если оба `Task` выбросят исключение и как в данном случае их нужно обрабатывать?

```
Task task1 = Method1Async();
Task task2 = Method2Async();
await task1;
await task2;
```

Comment: Зависит от версии .NET и от настроек в конфиг-файле. На текущей версии .NET исключение от 2-го таска проглотится.

Comment: @VladD, исключение от 2-го таска, или второе исключение?

Comment: @Mirdin: У ТС в условии оба таска бросают исключение. В коде как он есть `await task1` завершится с исключением и код до `await task2` просто не дойдёт.

Comment: Вопрос «как нужно обрабатывать» не имеет смысла. Контрвопрос — а что должно сделать приложение в случае, если приходят два исключения?

Comment: @VladD, Я так и ответил что исключение 2-го таска проглотится, только к сожалению не знал как отловить их оба. Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD `Task.WhenAll()` выбросит только одно исключение. Если нужна информация обо всех исключениях, это не вариант.

Comment: @andreycha: Хм, и правда. Странно, что так.

Comment: @VladD это было сделано в угоду консистентности: `await` всегда разворачивает `AggregateException`.

Comment: @andreycha: Понятно. В таком случае недолго и руками велосипед написать, если надо.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Сперва немного теории. Как известно, `async/await` представляет по сути лишь синтаксический сахар, за кулисами же компилятор разворачивает асинхронный код в чуть более сложный. Что происходит, когда в методе, помеченном модификатором `async`, возникает исключение? Оно не выбрасывается тотчас наверх по стеку (потому что к тому моменту мы уже можем быть в совершенно другом месте), а помещается внутрь таска (см. свойство `Exception`). Сам метод при этом завершается нормально. Исключение же (оригинальное или обернутое в `AggregateException`) будет выброшено в нескольких случаях:

- Кто-то ожидает таск (с помощью `await` или метода `Wait()`).
- Кто-то обращается к результату (свойство `Result`, применимо только для `Task<T>`).
- В случае если таск остался unobserved (т.е. его никто не дождался и не обратился к результату), то когда сборщик мусора добирается до таска и вызывает его финализатор, то финализатор видит, что в таске есть исключение и выбрасывает его. Как следствие, процесс падает. Важное замечание: такое поведение было включено по умолчанию до .NET 4.5. Начиная с .NET 4.5, финализатор не выбрасывает исключение, однако прежнее поведение может быть возвращено с помощью настройки [`ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj160346(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Исходя из этого, ответ на вопрос несколько "ветвист":

Вариант 1. Код работает под .NET младше 4.5, либо включена настройка `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions`.

В таком случае исключение для первого таска будет выброшено, исключение второго таска останется unobserved. Если где-то выше по стэку исключение от первого таска было обработано, и приложение продолжило работу, то рано оно поздно оно упадет -- когда финализатор второго таска выбросит исключение.

Вариант 2. Код работает под .NET 4.5 и выше и настройка `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` выключена.

В таком случае исключение для первого таска по-прежнему будет выброшено, исключение второго таска останется unobserved (увидеть его можно будет только подписавшись на событие [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx)), но процесс не упадет.

Вариантов обработки исключения несколько:

1. Обернуть каждый `await` в отдельный блок `try/catch`. Плюс этого варианта в том, что вы получите и обработаете оба исключения.
2. Использовать `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2)`. Минус этого варианта в том, что вы получите информацию только о первом исключении.
3. Использовать `Task.WaitAll(task1, task2)`. Плюс этого варианта в том, что вы получите `AggregateException`, который будет содержать в себе оба исключения. Минус этого варианта в том, что он блокирует текущий поток.

Comment: Спасибо, очень хороший ответ!

Comment: @Lightness не за что!

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос взят [отсюда](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/). Короткий ответ — процесс упадет до 4.5, а после — нет.

Comment: думаю автору интересны подробности а не всю доку перечитывать)

Comment: Всем не угодишь. Если не будешь доки перечитывать, то не поймешь откуда ноги растут. А за упрощения сразу в минусы вгонят, проверено.

Comment: *"а после — нет"* -- только если не включена настройка `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions`.

Answer (score 2):

Небольшое дополнение к ответу @andreycha (первый вариант обработки): если вы хотите получить все исключения в `AggregateException`, но при этом не использовать блокирующий `Task.WaitAll`, можно использовать такой вот велосипед:

```
static async Task WhenAllWithAllExceptions(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    var materialTasks = tasks.ToList(); // пробегаем список сейчас
    List<Exception> exceptions = null;
    bool hasExceptions = false;
    foreach (var task in materialTasks)
    {
        try
        {
            await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (exceptions == null)
                exceptions = new List<Exception>(materialTasks.Count);
            exceptions.Add(ex);
            hasExceptions = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasExceptions)
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}

static async Task<T[]> WhenAllWithAllExceptions<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var materialTasks = tasks.ToList(); // пробегаем список сейчас
    T[] results = null;
    List<Exception> exceptions = null;
    bool hasExceptions = false;
    int taskIndex = -1;
    foreach (var task in materialTasks)
    {
        taskIndex++;
        try
        {
            T t = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!hasExceptions)
            {
                if (results == null)
                    results = new T[materialTasks.Count];
                results[taskIndex] = t;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (exceptions == null)
                exceptions = new List<Exception>(materialTasks.Count);
            exceptions.Add(ex);
            hasExceptions = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasExceptions)
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    return results;
}
```

---

Обновление: по совету @Pavel Mayorov, добавил `ConfigureAwait`.

Comment: Ну да, это вариант 1 из моего ответа. Как я уже упоминал, не без минуса: теряется одно из преимуществ асинхронности. P.S. Кстати, флажок `hasExceptions` необязателен -- им может служить факт инициализации/наличия исключений в списке `exceptions`. И метод можно сделать extension-методом.

Comment: @andreycha: Я так и не понял, в чём недостаток. Задачи-то «горячие» в любом случае? Насчёт `hasExceptions` — формально от лишний, но мне показалось, что он добавляет читабельности (которая на мой взгляд важнее вообще всего).

Comment: Ох, да, туплю. Вы правы насчет задач. Обновил свой ответ заодно.

Comment: @andreycha: Поставил бы плюс, но не могу: уже поставлен.

Comment: Тот случай, когда `ConfigureAwait(false)` к месту.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Кстати, да. Добавил в ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD, Пересматривал заново Ваш ответ, и не смог понять, зачем нужен `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Не подскажите?

Comment: @Lightness: Без `ConfigureAwait(false)` хвост метода вернётся в исходный `SynchronizationContext` (то есть, в UI-поток). Поскольку нам это не особенно нужно (т. к. мы не делаем UI-специфических операций), будет дешевле, если мы разрешим в исходный поток не возвращаться. Именно это `ConfigureAwait(false)` и делает.

Comment: @VladD, Понял, спасибо!